# 1998 Honda xr650l starting problem

Tags: honda, motorcycle, fuel-system, carburetor

I have a 98 Honda xr650l it won't start ,it only starts when we attach a fuel pump to it(easily).when the fuel pump is removed it won't start again but it's not made to use a fuel pump we took down d carburetor cleaned it more than once it still won't start I really need help. Any recommendations will be greatly appreciated thanks (HELP!!!!!!!)

Comment: Did you check to ensure the fuel line isn't clogged?

Comment: Are you still having this issue or have you resolved it?

Answer (score 4):

The 1998 XL650 has a fuel petcock that has a safety feature on it, as do many other bikes of the gravity feed carb era from about 1980 to present.  Since you are running an XR650 you should not have the vacuum line.

There is a vacuum line that runs from the manifold side of the carb to the petcock on the XL650.  When the engine is turned over and creates vacuum in the line a diaphragm is opened in the petcock allowing fuel to flow.

I bring all this up because I was a Honda mechanic for years.  What I saw over and over were replaced petcocks with XL style rather than proper replacement.  I would have commented but my reputation is too low as I am new and cannot comment.

Additionally, there is a fuel filter that is integrated into the petcock and sitting in the gastank.  Ensure this filter is clear of debris by unscrewing the two screws that hold the petcock in the gastank.  There is a rubber o-ring that ensures a tight seal that may disintegrate upon removal of the petcock.  Hope this helpful and not just more noise.  Good luck.